# Vagrant -v Ignoring ffi -nokogiri and unf_ext because its extensions are not built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, vagrant, vagrant-provision

After trying to setup vagrant I get this output on flag -v

```
vagrant -v 
Ignoring ffi-1.9.14 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.14 
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7.1 
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.2 
Vagrant 2.0.0
```

Besides the above try suggestions I've already tried:

```
gem pristine --all
```

```
gem pristine --system
```

and with flag

```
-- --use-system-libraries
```

Also unistalled vagrant with:

```
rm -rf /opt/vagrant
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vagrant
sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
```

and install it again....Same thing!!!
I'm on **Mac OS X El Capitan** with ruby version :

```
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Problem still there!!!
Any suggestions? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

Problem finally solved by:

1. Completely uninstalling Vagrant 2.0.0 with:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant
   rm -f /usr/local/bin/vagrant
   sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
   ```
2. Removing the `~/.vagrant.d` directory.
3. Cleaning up the **old Vagrant gem** in Library>Ruby>Gems>2.0.0>gems.
4. Running this in terminal: `gem update`.
5. Reinstalling Vagrant from [Vagrant Official Site](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).

Installing Vagrant as a Ruby gem is no longer supported, and old versions have to be removed prior installing a newer version as is stated at the official site.